# SSRS 2008 Security - can't run reports

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have SSRS2008 set up and running locally on the server (SRV0100).  It is set up to run under the localsystem account for the service account (default).

I changed the rsreportserver.config to use RSWindowsNTLM.

I have set domain users up to have browser access to the reports.

However - on other PC's, when I try to get to the report, it says:

```
Error Message 401.3: You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials you supplied (access denied due to Access Control Lists). Ask the web server's administrator to give you access.
```

I added 'Everyone' to the report as well as domain\Domain Users.  Still the same issue even when restarting the SSRS service.

Any help?  I feel like I have read and tried everything :(

thanks in advance!

Andy

Answer (score 1):

ok, so called a buddy.  He mentioned another post that mentioned to grant the appropriate AD user(s) read and execute privilidges on the Reporting Services directory.

i did that and it worked.  Hopefully this helps someone else as well.